# Getting null values when retrieving Flows via Apex Metadata API

Tags: visual-workflow, metadata-api, metadata, null, mdapi

When attempting to retrieve Flow-specific data via the Apex Metadata API each value in the key-value pairs is null.  Here is the code:

```
private static void getFlowMetadata(Double apiVersion, MetadataService.MetadataPort mdService){

    List<String> lFlowNames = new List<String>();   
    List<String> lFlowNamesGroupedInTensTemp = new List<String>();
    List<List<String>> lFlowNamesGroupedInTens = new List<List<String>>();
    List<MetadataService.ListMetadataQuery> queries = new List<MetadataService.ListMetadataQuery>();        
    MetadataService.ListMetadataQuery queryWorkflow = new MetadataService.ListMetadataQuery();
    queryWorkflow.type_x = 'Flow';
    queries.add(queryWorkflow);         
    MetadataService.FileProperties[] lFileProperties = mdService.listMetadata(queries, apiVersion);

    // Since  the readMetadata method in the Apex Metadata API only supports ten records per call,
    // group each fileProperty queried into sets of ten
    for(Integer i = 0; i < lFileProperties.size(); i++){
        lFlowNames.add(lFileProperties[i].fullName);
        lFlowNamesGroupedInTensTemp.add(lFileProperties[i].fullName);

        if((Math.mod(i, 10) == 0) || (Math.mod(i, 10) != 0 && lFileProperties.size() - i < 10)){
            lFlowNamesGroupedInTens.add(lFlowNamesGroupedInTensTemp);
            lFlowNamesGroupedInTensTemp = new List<String>();
        }
    }

        MetadataService.Flow flowResult = (MetadataService.Flow) mdService.readMetadata('Flow', new List<String>{'CGS_Sold_Process_Manager_Flow'}).getRecords()[0];

        System.debug('flowResult ------> '+flowResult);
}
```

"flowResult" produces the following:

> Flow:[Metadata.fullName=null, actionCalls=null, actionCalls_type_info=(actionCalls, http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata, null, 0, -1, false), apexPluginCalls=null, apexPluginCalls_type_info=(apexPluginCalls, http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata, null, 0, -1, false), apex_schema_type_info=(http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata, true, false), assignments=null, assignments_type_info=(assignments, http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata, null, 0, -1, false), choices=nu..."

All keys are coming across as expected/desired.  But the values are null.  In contrast, when I call the tooling API for the data, it retrieves it just fine.

What is going on with Flows and the Metadata API?

Comment: What's the apiversion being passed in the code?

Comment: I'm passing in 40, currently.

Comment: Also tried 41 - 46 just in case; nada.